# Intermittent Tomcat ClassNotFoundException for some jsp pages

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

We have two tomcat servers load-balanced behind apache.  Several times now we'e gotten reports of a 500 error on a page.  Checking shows the following error, but only on one of the tomcats:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.jsps.userLogin_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    etc...
```

I've tried clearing the work directory and editing the jsp page, with no luck.  The only thing that solves it is a tomcat restart, but obviously we need to avoid this kind of solution in production.

Has anyone solved this problem before?  My searching has only found questions without answers, including a tomcat bug that was resolved as 'works for me': https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30450

I'd really appreciate any insight you have.  Here is some other info about the project:

- apache-tomcat-6.0.28
- java 1.6
- maven
- Spring 2.5 (heavy use of MVC with jstl)

Thanks!

Comment: If it's always the same Tomcat, does it fail even when only that server is in the cluster i.e. the other one shut down. I guess you cannot test that on Prod, do you have a pre-Production instance to replicate on? Is it always the same userLogin.jsp or other JSPs?

Comment: also see this thread, https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48097 though this would have made it into 6.0.21. Are you running with JspServlet  development = true

Comment: Thank you for the informative link!  Unfortunately this isn't something I've been able to reproduce.  I forgot about it at first, but we pushed a new war yesterday, and I forgot to clear the work directory before I started tomcat again.  I went ahead and did it after tomcat had started.  Do you think that could have caused this?

Comment: Clearing the work directory while Tomcat is running is not a good idea for a server that is in production.

Comment: Any chance there are other exceptions logged earlier?  It could be the result of something else like running out of memory.  It may have been unable to generate the servlet class file for some reason.

Comment: @samspot I agree with Mike, clearing the work dir while tomcat is running can result in such issues. Has happened on our production servers before. TC restart is what we did, we haven't found another fix so far.

Comment: Have you done a grep on all the logs for an OOM, try grep for heap? If it runs out of memory the vm tries to keep going unless you have the system property to kill on oom set and you can get some strange behaviour. Just a suggestion..

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the tip!  I looked at all the exceptions around that time and didn't see any OOM's.  At this point I'm pretty confident that my work directory clear is the culprit.  I haven't done that again and this issue has not come back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, I shouldn't be clearing the Tomcat's work directory while it is running.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

There's another instance I discovered, that may cause similar situations. I have two apps deployed in tomcat, and when I deploy the third one, I'm starting to observe this
behavior.

In this particular case I've found out that the tomcat with these three apps opens a lot of files, and it requires in this instance sometimes about 1600 files opened to work (system libs, jars, temps etc.). When it exceeds system default 1024 max opened files in some requests, it looks that some files cannot be opened and I have randomly strange errors
(including frequently ClassNotFoundException in jsp-s). All this depends on how quickly I click in these apps in browser windows, the files are opened and closed very quickly.

This helped for me and I no longer see problems with this instance:

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

This might be used to observe during the server runtime, what is the amount of opened files (if the tomcat is run as "tomcat" user):

```
while [ true ]; do lsof -u tomcat|wc -l; sleep 1s; done
```

Comment: We had to increase our ulimit in the past in order to solve some other issues we were having ("too many open files" in logs).  I think the ulimit setting is something that everyone is supposed to know about, but most of us find out the hard way!